# convert numeric(18,2) to varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(
    Val NUMERIC(18,2)
```

)

with the following values:

```
INSERT INTO @T SELECT 3.01
INSERT INTO @T SELECT 30
INSERT INTO @T SELECT 2.00
INSERT INTO @T SELECT 2.1
```

when I run this command:

```
SELECT * FROM @T
```

I get:

```
3.01
30.00
2.00
2.10
```

what I want to get is:

```
3.01
30
2
2.1
```

how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use a real number type instead. Following are the two ways.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(
    Val real
)

INSERT INTO @T SELECT 3.01
INSERT INTO @T SELECT 30
INSERT INTO @T SELECT 2.00
INSERT INTO @T SELECT 2.1

SELECT Val FROM @T
```

OR

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(
    Val NUMERIC(18,2)
)

INSERT INTO @T SELECT 3.01
INSERT INTO @T SELECT 30
INSERT INTO @T SELECT 2.00
INSERT INTO @T SELECT 2.1

SELECT cast(Val as real) FROM @T
```

Comment: that worked of course,I should I have thought about it!!!
just for my project here I did this:
    SELECT cast(cast(Val as real) as varchar) FROM @T

Comment: `REAL` is not safe, not accurate - it's subject to rounding errors. I would advise **against** using `REAL` ....

Answer (score 1):

Completely hackish, but a simple solution. But, it's not subject to rounding errors.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(
    Val NUMERIC(18,2)
)

INSERT INTO @T SELECT 3.01
INSERT INTO @T SELECT 30.00
INSERT INTO @T SELECT 2.0
INSERT INTO @T SELECT 2.10
INSERT INTO @T SELECT 2.20
INSERT INTO @T SELECT 2.30
INSERT INTO @T SELECT 2.40
INSERT INTO @T SELECT 2.50
INSERT INTO @T SELECT 2.60
INSERT INTO @T SELECT 2.70
INSERT INTO @T SELECT 2.80
INSERT INTO @T SELECT 2.90

select
    replace(
    replace(
    replace(
    replace(
    replace(
    replace(
    replace(
    replace(
    replace(
    replace(
        convert(varchar,Val)
    ,'.00','')
    ,'.10','.1')
    ,'.20','.2')
    ,'.30','.3')
    ,'.40','.4')
    ,'.50','.5')
    ,'.60','.6')
    ,'.70','.7')
    ,'.80','.8')
    ,'.90','.9')
from @T
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT Cast(Val AS Float) from @T
```